# prevent bulk write operation if any matches are found

Tags: mongodb

I can't really seem to figure this out although it seems like it shouldn't be a difficult problem.. basically I want to ensure that no documents exists within a mongo batch operation and then either fail if any are found or proceed to insert them all. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this - you essentially want a multi-document insert transaction under the failure condition of a collision on `_id`? Can you explain more about the requirement? It might help in devising a good solution.

Comment: So basically I have one document which contains a list of items - essentially a shopping cart. The items in this cart can potentially be paid for by multiple people and so to prevent a double payment, I need to lock the items once someone requests to pay for them. However, if that someone doesn't pay for them within a certain amount of time, let's say 3 minutes, the lock needs to be automatically removed (auto expirery) which is why I need to create a secondary set of "lock" documents for each item.

Comment: If a document exists already for any one item, I need to fail the entire request, other wise, I need to create the new docs. The problem is that this needs to be done within the same query to prevent any secondary requests passing the checks before the documents have been written. (e.g. prevention of race conditions)

Comment: I just decided for now to go ahead and do a find/upsert/update and then compare the upserted results against the items I want to lock. However, it would be really nice if I could specify custom keys to be returned in the upserted results instead of just index and _id.